# problem regarding time series modeling using R

Tags: r, time-series, self-study, stationarity

I have this time series data and my aim is to fit a time series model. 
When i plot the time series data , it seems to be data is not stationary.
[image]

These are the plots based on the first difference,

[image]
But when i try to  estimate the coefficients using auto.arima, i got the model as AR(1)

```
data <- read.csv("dj.csv", sep="")
datats=ts(data$DJ)
par(mfcol = c(3, 1))

plot(diff(datats))
acf(diff(datats))
pacf(diff(datats))
auto.arima(datats)

    Series: datats 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
         ar1      mean
      0.9022  873.1948
s.e.  0.0326   27.9480

sigma^2 estimated as 1328:  log likelihood=-787.11
AIC=1580.22   AICc=1580.37   BIC=1589.38
```

What might be the reason for this? Did i do anything wrong ?

Data set link : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1m81mhYg18lRZmPpixmGw4bKZ7xciKTC_

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your model has an ar value of .90 which is nearly 1.0 .. if it was larger say .999 it could be labelled (semantically) a first difference model thus non-stationary. A more robust model including the identification of a few anomalies is here [image] yielding a value of .92 . In this case your model is adequate as the 5 anomalies have little real effect on model identification and you are doing nothing wrong (in this case !)

The Actual/Cleansed graph highlights the 5 anomalies [image]